# mac m1 cannot open a file after it is modified using radare2

Tags: macos, radare2

I'm learning to use radare2 and I'm following the same process as other blogs but I'm having problems

The code is as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int secret = 0;
  printf("Please input the secret number:");
  scanf("%d",&secret);
  if(secret != 123)
  {
    printf("error secret number!\n");
    return 0;
  }
  printf("Success!\n");
}
```

compile and run:

```bash
➜  practice gcc main.c -o main
➜  practice ./main
Please input the secret number:12
error secret number!
➜  practice ./main
Please input the secret number:123
Success!
➜  practice
```

I want to change my judgment with radare2

```bash
➜  practice r2 -A -w main
WARN: Relocs has not been applied. Please use `-e bin.relocs.apply=true` or `-e bin.cache=true` next time
INFO: Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
INFO: Analyze imports (af@@@i)
INFO: Analyze entrypoint (af@ entry0)
INFO: Analyze symbols (af@@@s)
INFO: Recovering variables
INFO: Analyze all functions arguments/locals (afva@@@F)
INFO: Analyze function calls (aac)
INFO: Analyze len bytes of instructions for references (aar)
INFO: Check for objc references (aao)
INFO: Finding and parsing C++ vtables (avrr)
INFO: Analyzing methods
INFO: Finding function preludes (aap)
INFO: Finding xrefs in noncode section (e anal.in=io.maps.x)
INFO: Emulate functions to find computed references (aaef)
INFO: Recovering local variables (afva)
INFO: Type matching analysis for all functions (aaft)
INFO: Propagate noreturn information (aanr)
INFO: Use -AA or aaaa to perform additional experimental analysis
[0x100003ed4]> iz
[Strings]
nth paddr      vaddr       len size section            type  string
―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
0   0x00003f74 0x100003f74 31  32   2.__TEXT.__cstring ascii Please input the secret number:
1   0x00003f97 0x100003f97 21  22   2.__TEXT.__cstring ascii error secret number!\n
2   0x00003fad 0x100003fad 9   10   2.__TEXT.__cstring ascii Success!\n
[0x100003ed4]> pdf
            ;-- section.0.__TEXT.__text:
            ;-- entry0:
            ;-- _main:
            ;-- func.100003ed4:
            ;-- pc:
            ; NULL XREF from aav.0x100000020 @ +0xb0(r)
┌ 136: int main (int argc, int64_t argv);
│           ; arg int argc @ x0
│           ; arg int64_t argv @ sp+0x60
│           ; var int64_t var_0h_2 @ sp+0x0
│           ; var int64_t var_10h @ sp+0x10
│           ; var int64_t var_8h @ sp+0x18
│           ; var int64_t var_0h @ sp+0x1c
│           ; var int64_t var_20h @ sp+0x20
│           ; var int64_t var_20h_2 @ sp+0x28
│           0x100003ed4      ffc300d1       sub sp, sp, 0x30           ; [00] -r-x section size 136 named 0.__TEXT.__text
│           0x100003ed8      fd7b02a9       stp x29, x30, [var_20h]
│           0x100003edc      fd830091       add x29, var_20h
│           0x100003ee0      bfc31fb8       stur wzr, [x29, -4]        ; argc
│           0x100003ee4      a82300d1       sub x8, x29, 8
│           0x100003ee8      e80b00f9       str x8, [var_10h]
│           0x100003eec      bf831fb8       stur wzr, [x29, -8]        ; argc
│           0x100003ef0      00000090       adrp x0, 0x100003000
│           0x100003ef4      00d03d91       add x0, x0, 0xf74          ; 0x100003f74 ; "Please input the secret number:" ; const char *format
│           0x100003ef8      19000094       bl sym.imp.printf          ; int printf(const char *format)
│           0x100003efc      e80b40f9       ldr x8, [var_10h]          ; 5
│           0x100003f00      e9030091       mov x9, sp
│           0x100003f04      280100f9       str x8, [x9]
│           0x100003f08      00000090       adrp x0, 0x100003000
│           0x100003f0c      00503e91       add x0, x0, 0xf94          ; const char *format
│           0x100003f10      16000094       bl sym.imp.scanf           ; int scanf(const char *format)
│           0x100003f14      a8835fb8       ldur w8, [x29, -8]
│           0x100003f18      08ed0171       subs w8, w8, 0x7b
│           0x100003f1c      e8179f1a       cset w8, eq
│       ┌─< 0x100003f20      e8000037       tbnz w8, 0, 0x100003f3c
│      ┌──< 0x100003f24      01000014       b 0x100003f28
│      ││   ; CODE XREF from main @ 0x100003f24(x)
│      └──> 0x100003f28      00000090       adrp x0, 0x100003000
│       │   0x100003f2c      005c3e91       add x0, x0, 0xf97          ; 0x100003f97 ; "error secret number!\n" ; const char *format
│       │   0x100003f30      0b000094       bl sym.imp.printf          ; int printf(const char *format)
│       │   0x100003f34      bfc31fb8       stur wzr, [x29, -4]
│      ┌──< 0x100003f38      05000014       b 0x100003f4c
│      ││   ; CODE XREF from main @ 0x100003f20(x)
│      │└─> 0x100003f3c      00000090       adrp x0, 0x100003000
│      │    0x100003f40      00b43e91       add x0, x0, 0xfad          ; 0x100003fad ; "Success!\n" ; const char *format
│      │    0x100003f44      06000094       bl sym.imp.printf          ; int printf(const char *format)
│      │┌─< 0x100003f48      01000014       b 0x100003f4c
│      ││   ; CODE XREFS from main @ 0x100003f38(x), 0x100003f48(x)
│      └└─> 0x100003f4c      a0c35fb8       ldur w0, [x29, -4]
│           0x100003f50      fd7b42a9       ldp x29, x30, [var_20h]
│           0x100003f54      ffc30091       add sp, argv
└           0x100003f58      c0035fd6       ret
[0x100003ed4]> s 0x100003f20
[0x100003f20]> wa tbz w8, 0, 0x100003f3c
INFO: Written 4 byte(s) (tbz w8, 0, 0x100003f3c) = wx e8000036 @ 0x100003f20
[0x100003f20]> q
```

run main:

```bash
➜  practice ./main
[1]    57065 killed     ./main
```

I found many tutorials that worked in this step, but when I tried to open them with r2, I got an error. I used hopper to see that the change was successful, but I don't know why it didn't work.
[image]